# Projection of a vector along A cross B

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, geometry

.I want to find projection  of A+B vector along A × B.(cross product )

A vector = i - j +k cap

B vector = j+2k

I am not able to think about correctly.Pls help in how to draw a diagram in such cases when you have a k cap like here.How to draw it in my notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is always zero. This is because $A+B$ (as well as any linear combination of $A$ and $B$) will lie on the plane defined by $A$ and $B$.

But the cross product $A\times B$ is *always* perpendicular to this plane, thus you have the identities

$$ A \cdot ( A  \times B) = 0 $$
$$ B \cdot ( A  \times B) = 0 $$

which leads to

$$ (A+B) \cdot ( A  \times B) = 0 $$

And if there is zero component of $A$ or $B$ along $A\times B$ then the projection vector also has zero magnitude.

Comment: Why does it have zero magnitude but ? and can we say the angle between the two is 90

Comment: By the identity , Shouldn’t it be C (resultant of A+B) .(A cross B).

Comment: $(A+B)$ will lie on the same plane as $A$ and $B$. The cross product $A\times B$ will be perpendicular to the plane formed by $A$ and $B$. Since $(A+B)$ lies on that same plane, and the dot product of two orthogonal vectors is $0$, then you have $(A+B)\cdot(A\times B)=0$

Comment: @user256872 thank you very much,

Comment: @John Thank you as well.

Comment: @Qmechanic Pls do give a specific reason why did you vote for closing my question.How is it off topic of vectors.

Comment: @Qmechanic I agree with _op_, sometimes here at [Physics.SE] we tend to close questions that we might find trivial. We forget maybe that our audience is broad in experience, and if _someone_ is willing to answer a question, it should remain open.